# lib_mysqludf_preg returns a hash instead of string

Tags: mysql, preg-replace, pcre

I'll start off by saying that I have successfully installed this mysql udf on at least 6 servers in the past, but our new database cluster is making me pull my hair out. The udf is found here: `https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg`

We're running percona's build of `mysql 5.5.36-34 on centos 6.5.` We have tried installing every release version of lib_mysqludf_preg, and in each case it isn't working properly. When I check the version number with lib_mysqludf_preg_info(), I get back a hash: `6c69625f6d7973716c7564665f7072656720312e31`
Instead of the expected version number.

`SELECT CONVERT( PREG_REPLACE( '/fox/i' , 'dog' , 'The brown fox' ) USING UTF8) as replaced;` 
returns The brown dog which is ok.

`SELECT PREG_CAPTURE('/(.*?)(fox)/' , 'the quick brown fox' ,2 );`
 Should return `FOX`", but our install returns: `666f78`

Unless we change the query to:
 `SELECT CONVERT( PREG_CAPTURE('/(.*?)(fox)/' , 'the quick brown fox' ,2 ) USING UTF8)`

We've been using this plugin for years, and we have never had to use the CONVERT, or USING `UTF-8`.
 Any ideas?